# Getting NoClassDefFoundError for org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext while packaging a jar using Maven

Tags: spring, pom.xml

I am sure this question was asked before also. I had already tried other options as mentioned but not successful :(

**BackGround:** Packaging a jar with all dependencies using maven.

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>assembly:package</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <!-- Work around for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-97 
                    as the goal should be attached. -->
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.Application</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>config/</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**classPath**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" />
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" />
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con"
        path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER" />
    <classpathentry kind="con"
        path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre7" />
</classpath>
```

When I am running the exported jar using

```
java -cp Scheduler-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exe.jar com.Application
```

I am getting exception as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/c
ontext/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
        at com.Application.main(Application.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.support
.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Any ideas on this? I am using spring version 3.0.6 for all dependant jars.

Thanks
Gendaful

Comment: if you specify com.Application as a main class when packing JAR you can run it using `java -jar Scheduler-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exe.jar` command, this should also include all dependencies into classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath you mentioned is that of eclipse project. It is not considered by the maven build tool while preparing the JAR using build target. You should specify the spring jars as dependencies in your pom.xml as follows, for them to be considered by Maven during packaging the application.

```
<dependencies>
    ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    ...
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this plugin in your pom.xml plugins.

```
      <!-- Adding depenencies to jar file -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
         <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```